# Will an array inside of a JavaScript function be recreated on every call?

Tags: javascript, function, v8, spidermonkey, javascriptcore

Suppose I've got a function, `dayToString`, defined as such:

```
function dayToString(n) {
  return ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"][n];
}
```

Easy enough. Usage could look something like this:

```
var d = new Date();

var todayAsString = dayToString(d.getDay());
```

My question is, is the array within `dayToString` recreated on every call, or is it only created once?

**Edit**

A clarification: I know how to manually avoid this reallocation via a closure or an external array. To clarify my original intent: Are the current JavaScript engines (V8, SpiderMonkey, JavaScriptCore, Chakra, etc.) smart enough to realize that the array is static and treat is as such? Is there perhaps something in the JS spec that prevents such an optimization?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are defining it and returning it every call. To avoid this, define outside the function:

```
var arrayOfDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
function dayToString(n) {
  return arrayOfDays[n];
}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this method to avoid what we assume to be reallocation, but I meant this question to be more geared towards V8, JSC, and friends are able to see this static item inside a function and treat it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the array is recreated every time.

To create the array only once you can:

1) Emulate a `static property` on the function:

```
dayToString.weekDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
function dayToString(n) {
  return dayToString.weekDays[n];
}
```

2) Or create a `closure to keep the week days` isolated:

```
var dayToString = (function(n) {
  var weekDays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
  return function(n) {
    return weekDays[n];
  }
})();
```

Comment: A fine trick in your 2 that I use often enough to have generalized into a function that takes an array and returns the closure, but my question was meant to be more of a question of how "smart" the JS engines are. Do they realize the array is static on their own and treat it as such?

Comment: @HoagyCarmichael It depends on the implementation, and there is a big chance that the engine can optimize this part. But I won't take this as an argument in coding phase, because JavaScript specification says that the scope is recreated each time on function call.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the runtime compiler. So the question can not be aswered with yes or no.

But I say, No, because there is only one instance of the function and the content of the function is static, in the view of the compiler.

Comment: This is the sort of optimization I was considering when asking the question. I'm not familiar enough with the V8, JSC, etc. source to find whether this optimization is done in any reasonable amount of time, but if you have anything to back your claims, that's what I'm after.